# Front-end javascript to hide/use environmental variables?

Tags: javascript

I don't have Node.js experience and would like to make a basic webpage that will be using some sensitive data/API passwords. Is it possible for me to use environmental variables to obfuscate/protect this data? I've been researching Webpack and just wondering if I can use that on the front-end alone to deal with everything.

Comment: Why would you send passwords to the client at all?

Comment: You can't use environment variables in runtime at browser.

Comment: of course not... why don't you scan and put your credit card information on the streets.

Comment: I think maybe your question is just poorly worded and people aren't understanding properly, well either them or me. The preferred method for handing things like DB Creds and UN/PW to your Node app is in fact environment variables. You can access them via process.env.ENV_VARIABLE

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to really hide any sensitive information just by frontend, even if you obfuscate the source code.

Users can break it in many simple ways to dig every piece of sensitive information out.
e.g. inject arbitrary js function in console, put breakpoints into your js code, inspect the network calls fired by browser, or wireshark the network traffic.

You need a server to hide anything you don't want to expose.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was actually looking to run node-static and just wrap my static website inside nodejs on heroku and use their built-in environmental variables feature. Would this be safe?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to keep secret while still keeping your web functional to user. However rule of thumbs is, if you try to put it in frontend script or html, no matter though hard code or env vars, it will not be safe.

Comment: You should only use your environmental variables in node.js server code, and never directly send them to your users.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I choose one of approaches:

1. You can't hide sensitive data on client side but you can on server side - so use backend as proxy between your client and sensitive data
2. When you can't allow server solutions I can recommend to minify/uglify javascript bundle code to harder understand what secrets you use